# Storing binary with JDBCTemplate

Tags: sql-server, jdbctemplate

I have table like
`create table test(payload varbinary(max))`

I am trying to store text lines in compressed format in the database using the following code

```
String sql = "insert into test(payload) values (compress(:payload))
MapSqlParametersource msps = new MapSqlParameterSource();
msps.addValue("payload", "some text", Types.VARBINARY)
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npjt = //;
npjt.update(sql, msps);
```

This gives the following error -

> String is not in a valid hex format

If I provide the datatype in MapSqlParameterSource as VARCHAR, it doesn't give any error, but then using MSSQL's `decompress` function returns garbage value

`select decompress(payload) from test`

Comment: What version of Java are you using? What bytes do you think Java should be storing in the `varbinary` column? Before Java 9 the `String` type internally stored UTF-16 encoded text (effectively 2 or 4 bytes per code point depending on the code point), since then it tries to use compact strings if it thinks all of the code points are valid within the Latin-1 encoding.

Comment: i am using java 15

Comment: Well `VARBINARY` types in SQL Server map best to byte arrays (`byte[]`) in Java. Have you tried something like `"some text".getBytes("UTF-8")` to send a string with a specific text encoding as a byte array?